# свернуть окно в vb 6

Tags: visual-basic, vb6

можно ли в vb6 свернуть окно приложения. с выходом всё прост

```
Private Sub buttMin_Click()
   'свернуть окно?
End Sub

Private Sub buttExit_Click()
   End 'закрыть окно
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно свернуть окно приложения в VB6 с помощью метода Minimize:

```
Me.WindowState = vbMinimized
```

Данный метод устанавливает состояние окна на "свернутое". Можно вызвать его, например, при нажатии на кнопку:

```
Private Sub cmdMinimize_Click()
    Me.WindowState = vbMinimized
End Sub
```